# Access to data by multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have an application that I have written, I have three thread. Thread 1, 2 and 3.

And two lists of numbers 1 and 2.

Thread No. 1 insert data into list No.1.

Thread No. 2 get data from list No.1.

Thread No. 2 insert data into list No.2.

Thread No. 3 get data from list No.2.

If threads are running simultaneously occupy a lot of CPU. Data may be entered in the list, number two and number three running thread is not needed.

How to notify that the threads in the list of new data is inserted and They need to start working on a new data processing do?

Techniques and efficient way to reach you?

thanks a lot, a lot.

Comment: you need a bounded buffer with semaphores, you can find an example in Martin Harvey's excellent threading tutorial here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=14809

Comment: That's a pipeline. Get OTL and look at the pipeline examples.

Comment: As David has said, OTL may be your friend here: http://otl.17slon.com/book/doku.php?id=book:highlevel:pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample that adds values in list1 and list2 from your three threads.

Each time a value is put into a list, an `Event` is triggered and the thread handling this event pulls out the last value in the list and clears the event flag.

No new value can be put into a list until the event flag is cleared.

The middle thread makes an intermediate storage of a new value, not to stall the first thread.

All events are waitable and thus keeps the cpu at ease.

The lists are thread-safe.

```
program Project62;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.SyncObjs,
  System.Generics.Collections;

Type
  TMyThread1 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMySyncAddList : TSimpleEvent;
      fMyList : TThreadList<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(ASyncAddList: TSimpleEvent; AList: TThreadList<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;
  TMyThread2 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMySyncAddList1,fMySyncAddList2 : TSimpleEvent;
      fMyList1,fMyList2 : TThreadList<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(ASyncAddList1,ASyncAddList2: TSimpleEvent; AList1,AList2 : TThreadList<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;
  TMyThread3 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMySyncAddList2 : TSimpleEvent;
      fMyList2 : TThreadList<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(ASyncAddList2: TSimpleEvent; AList2 : TThreadList<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;


{ TMyThread1 }

constructor TMyThread1.Create( ASyncAddList : TSimpleEvent; AList: TThreadList<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMySyncAddList := AsyncAddList;
  fMyList := AList;

end;

procedure TMyThread1.Execute;
var
  stateAcknowledged : boolean;
begin
  stateAcknowledged := true;
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    if stateAcknowledged then
    begin // Do some work and adda a value to list1
      fAddVal := Random(100);
      fMyList.Add(fAddVal);
      fMySyncAddList.SetEvent; // Signal a new addition
      stateAcknowledged := false;
      //ShowVal;
      Sleep(1000);
    end
    else begin
      stateAcknowledged := (fMySyncAddList.WaitFor(100) <> wrSignaled);
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TMyThread2 }

constructor TMyThread2.Create(ASyncAddList1, ASyncAddList2: TSimpleEvent;
  AList1, AList2: TThreadList<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMySyncAddList1 := AsyncAddList1;
  fMySyncAddList2 := AsyncAddList2;
  fMyList1 := AList1;
  fMyList2 := AList2;    
end;

procedure TMyThread2.Execute;
var
  wr : TWaitResult;
  list : TList<Integer>;
  pulled : Boolean;
begin
  pulled := false;
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    if pulled then // Add a value to list2
    begin
      wr := fMySyncAddList2.WaitFor(0);
      if (wr <> wrSignaled) then
      begin
        fMyList2.Add(fAddVal);
        fMySyncAddList2.SetEvent; // Signal a new addition
        pulled := false;
      end
      else Sleep(100);
    end
    else begin // Wait for a new value in list1
      wr := fMySyncAddList1.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      if Terminated then
        Exit;
      if (wr = wrSignaled) then
      begin
        // Pull out the value
        list := fMyList1.LockList;
        try
          fAddVal := list.Last;
        finally
          fMyList1.UnlockList;
        end;
        // All clear
        pulled := true;
        fMySyncAddList1.ResetEvent;
        //ShowVal;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TMyThread3 }

constructor TMyThread3.Create(ASyncAddList2: TSimpleEvent;
  AList2: TThreadList<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMySyncAddList2 := AsyncAddList2;
  fMyList2 := AList2;
end;

procedure TMyThread3.Execute;
var
  wr : TWaitResult;
  list : TList<Integer>;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    wr := fMySyncAddList2.WaitFor(INFINITE);
    if Terminated then
      Exit;
    if (wr = wrSignaled)  then // Wait for signal
    begin
      // Pull out the value
      list := fMyList2.LockList;
      try
        fAddVal := list.Last;
        //ShowVal;
      finally
        fMyList2.UnlockList;
      end;
      // Clear event
      fMySyncAddList2.ResetEvent;
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  list1,list2 : TThreadList<Integer>;
  syncList1,syncList2 : TSimpleEvent;
  thread1 : TMyThread1;
  thread2 : TMyThread2;
  thread3 : TMyThread3;
begin
  list1 := TThreadList<Integer>.Create;
  list2 := TThreadList<Integer>.Create;
  syncList1 := TSimpleEvent.Create(Nil,True,False,'',false);
  syncList2 := TSimpleEvent.Create(Nil,True,False,'',false);
  thread3 := TMyThread3.Create(syncList2,list2);
  thread2 := TMyThread2.Create(syncList1,syncList2,list1,list2);
  thread1 := TMyThread1.Create(syncList1,list1);
  Try
    WriteLn('Press [Enter] key to stop.');
    ReadLn;

  Finally
    thread3.Terminate;
    syncList2.SetEvent; // Wake up call
    thread3.Free;
    thread2.Terminate;
    syncList1.SetEvent; // Wake up call
    thread2.Free;
    thread1.Free;
    syncList1.Free;
    syncList2.Free;
    list1.Free;
    list2.Free;
  End;
end.
```

---

Added an example where two `TThreadedQueue`'s transfer the information between the threads. The threads keeps internal lists of the integers instead. The code is much simpler as @DavidHeffernan points out.

```
program Project63;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.SyncObjs,
  System.Generics.Collections;

Type
  TMyThread1 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMyList : TList<Integer>;
      fMyQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(AQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;
  TMyThread2 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMyList1,fMyList2 : TList<Integer>;
      fMyQueue1,fMyQueue2 : TThreadedQueue<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(AQueue1,AQueue2: TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;
  TMyThread3 = Class(TThread)
    private
      fMyList : TList<Integer>;
      fMyQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>;
      fAddVal : Integer;
    public
      Constructor Create(AQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
      procedure Execute; override;
  End;

constructor TMyThread1.Create( AQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMyQueue:= AQueue;
  fMyList := TList<Integer>.Create;
end;

procedure TMyThread1.Execute;
begin
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    Sleep(1000); // Simulate some work
    fAddVal := Random(100);
    fMyList.Add(fAddVal);
    fMyQueue.PushItem(fAddVal); // Signal a new addition
  end;
  fMyList.Free;
end;

constructor TMyThread2.Create(AQueue1,AQueue2: TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMyQueue1 := AQueue1;
  fMyQueue2 := AQueue2;
  fMyList1 := TList<Integer>.Create;
  fMyList2 := TList<Integer>.Create;
end;

procedure TMyThread2.Execute;
var
  queueSize : Integer;
begin
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    if (fMyQueue1.PopItem(queueSize,fAddVal) = wrSignaled) and 
       (not Terminated) then
    begin
      fMyList1.Add(fAddVal);
      // Do some work and send a new value to next thread
      fMyQueue2.PushItem(fAddVal);
      fMyList2.Add(fAddVal);
      
    end;
  end;
  fMyList1.Free;
  fMyList2.Free;
end;

constructor TMyThread3.Create(AQueue : TThreadedQueue<Integer>);
begin
  Inherited Create(false);
  fMyQueue := AQueue;
  fMyList := TList<Integer>.Create;
end;

procedure TMyThread3.Execute;
var
  queueSize : Integer;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if (fMyQueue.PopItem(queueSize,fAddVal) = wrSignaled) and 
       (not Terminated) then
    begin
      fMyList.Add(fAddVal);
      // Do some work on list
      
    end;
  end;
  fMyList.Free;
end;

var
  queue1,queue2 : TThreadedQueue<Integer>;
  thread1 : TMyThread1;
  thread2 : TMyThread2;
  thread3 : TMyThread3;
begin
  queue1 := TThreadedQueue<Integer>.Create;
  queue2 := TThreadedQueue<Integer>.Create;
  thread3 := TMyThread3.Create(queue2);
  thread2 := TMyThread2.Create(queue1,queue2);
  thread1 := TMyThread1.Create(queue1);
  Try
    WriteLn('Press [Enter] key to stop.');
    ReadLn;

  Finally
    thread3.Terminate;
    queue2.PushItem(0); // Wake up call
    thread3.Free;
    thread2.Terminate;
    queue1.PushItem(0); // Wake up call
    thread2.Free;
    thread1.Free;
    queue1.Free;
    queue2.Free;
  End;
end.
```

Comment: Very low level. Don't you just build a threadsafe queue, and instantiate two of them.

Comment: And waking up 10 times a second? Why?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, modified code to better sleep periods. About not using queues: it seems as thread 2 wants access to both list1 and list2. Not only the last item added, but the whole list. And the same for thread 3 and list2. If you could rule that out, yes a queue would be much easier.

Comment: The consumers can pull off the data and maintain their own private lists with copies of the data. This is 10 times as long as it needs to be, and uses sleep timeouts which are vile. You should never use sleep or timeouts in a pipeline. In fact sleep should always be shunned. It's trivial with a pair of threadsafe queues.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sleep infinite is vile? Making copies can work, but details of how they are worked upon are missing.

Comment: Copies are great because that isolates the data and relieves you of the need for synhronisations. Sharing is the root off most threading complexity.

Comment: @David, added an example based on queues. Yes, code is much simpler and hopefully fits OP's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is semaphores. Semaphore is a synchronization primitive with a counter inside: one thread tries to decrement the counter, and if it's zero, the thread blocks (i.e. is not scheduled and doesn't eat CPU, just waits harmlessly). Another thread increments the counter, causing blocked thread(s) to continue.

You may have a semaphore for each list, so a consuming thread decrements the semaphore before reading, and a producer thread increments it after writing.

There is another thing to take care of: is it allowed for one thread to get data from list while another thread is modifying it? It depends on how lists (or collections in general) are implemented, so try to find something on "thread safety" of Lists in your documentation. Maybe you need another synchronization primite: mutex. Mutexes are "taken" and then "released" by threads, and when more than one thread attempts to lock a mutex, one of them has to wait. One mutex per list, with modifications and reads done with this mutex held, may be appropriate here.

Comment: 'producer thread increments it before writing' - nope!  AFTER writing!